# Using Android WorkManager for local Notification instead of AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-workmanager

User selects a time to notify a message as a reminder that could repeat for everyday or only on certain day of the week.Previously I did this task by setting time to AlarmManager

```
        Calendar calSet= Calendar.getInstance();
        //calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek); for a particular day of the week
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs));
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min));
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00); 
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Now AlarmManager stops working when the device is at Doze .I cannot use [setAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent) because I need to repeat the notification message.
 Now I have one option to use WorkerManager,but I have no idea of how to set the time as done in AlarmManager

```
      PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SetJobWork.class,1,TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .addTag(Id).setConstraints(constraints).build()
```

Suppose I need to run the task at 1.00 pm daily,what is the way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I have one option to use WorkerManager,but I have no idea of how to set the time as done in AlarmManager

`WorkManager` does not support your scenario, sorry.

> I cannot use setAndAllowWhileIdle because I need to repeat the notification message.

You can manually repeat by calling `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` to schedule the next alarm as part of processing the `PendingIntent` for your last alarm.